# dupes in angular when using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular and ng-repeat isnt working for me.

My first ng-repeat works but the second one where im using a json string isn't. Its complaining about ng-repeat dupes but I dont understand why. What I'm I doing wrong?

see the code here
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8c9x/)

or here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app ng-controller="AController">

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in firstTest">
                {{item}}
            </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in secondTest">
                {{item}}
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AController($scope) {
            $scope.firstTest = {
                a: "123",
                b: "234"
            };

            $scope.secondTest = '[{"Price": 123,"ProductName": "apple"},{"Price": 234,"ProductName": "pear"}]';
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use JSON directly you have to deserialize the JSON to JS Objects as shown in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d8c9x/1/).

> [JSON.Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="AController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in firstTest">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in secondTest">
            {{item.Price}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function AController($scope) {
    $scope.firstTest = {
        a: "123",
        b: "234"
    };

    $scope.secondTest = JSON.parse('[{"Price": 123,"ProductName": "apple"},{"Price": 234,"ProductName": "pear"}]');
}
```

Comment: aaah, thats why. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Parse it
http://jsfiddle.net/64dAE/

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in secondTest">
        {{item.Price}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**js:**

```
$scope.secondTest = JSON.parse('[{"Price": 123,"ProductName": "apple"},{"Price": 234,"ProductName": "pear"}]');
```

Comment: Any js code works with real instances. JSON is always parsed at some point. Angular is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.secondTest= JSON.parse($scope.secondTest);
```