# Why am I getting ng-repeat dupe error when I use a for loop instead of if statement?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The code in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JwFyE0Y1ehYuN1LvYqXI?p=preview) works as it should (just the first 3 links do something). But as the list started to grow I realized I needed a for loop. So within the `switch function` I transformed this:

```
  if(obj == "SP") {
    $scope.discipline ='Link2'
    return $scope.files = spFiles;
  }
  else if(obj == "LSM"){
    $scope.discipline = "Link3"
    return $scope.files = lsmFiles;
  }
  else if(obj == "AR"){
    $scope.discipline = "Link1"
    return $scope.files = arFiles;
  }
```

Into this:

```
for(i=0;i<disciplines.length;i++){
   if(obj == disciplines[i].initial){
       return $scope.files = disciplines[i].array;
   }
}
```

The disciplines array is located at the top of the script.js file.

Problem is, now suddenly I am getting a dupes error when I click on one of the links. I haven't a clue what is duplicating. I read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) for this error and added the `track by $index` to the `ng-repeat` located on the bottom of index.html. Take a look at [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0yrHmtrQ8aMx88jJLHZ?p=preview) to see what it does now. Certainly there is a simple explanation for this. I've never encountered this though.

The only other answer I could find on here that seems to pertain to my question is [this one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186527/dupes-in-angular-when-using-ng-repeat) but, the object that is being used by the `ng-repeat` isn't a JSON object I'm pretty sure:

```
spFiles.push({
      floor:floors[c].name, initial:floors[c].initial, status:spFloorStatus[i]
});
```

Plus, it was working before I created the for loop causing the trouble.

I apologize if anything is unclear. Please, if you need me to clarify anything just let me know, I tried to be as thorough and as least confusing as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because disciplines[i].array return just string, not your variable, named arFiles.

You can initialize these variables as:

```
var tempFiles={};
```

and then add:

```
tempFiles.arFiles={
      floor:floors[c].name, initial:floors[c].initial, status:arFloorStatus[i]
    };
```

and get :

```
return $scope.files = tempFiles[disciplines[i].array];
```

Comment: You will need to elaborate on that or update the plunker to work how you are saying.

Comment: What happens when I make an attempt at what you are saying, when I alert(tempFiles.arFiles.floor); I get "Penthouse" which means it is overwriting the "array" every time rather than adding to it as I was when I was using .push()